# Manhwa where the female lead has to follow a guidebook to survive

Tags: story-identification, manga, time-travel, reincarnation

I remember reading this manhwa where the female lead is reincarnated in a story. There, she has to follow a guidebook. She thought that after the story ends she will be able to go back. But after the ending, she rather goes back into the past and this time there was no guidebook, which was a must to follow. Now she is confused what to do without the guidebook. What's more, after going back in past, the main character starts behaving differently than he was supposed to behave. Things were not progressing like in the storyline.

That's all I remember.

Comment: What sort of world and time period was the story set in? And do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Also, did the female lead have a literal, physical guidebook that she could flip open and read in the other world? Or was she just going by her memory of the original plot, having read such a book in her previous life?

Comment: You mean a system? And after reset, it was revealed that other MC request it so they can flirt with her again. Also The system fake his disapear with the "will of the world" so no one can't interfer FMC anymore.